# Form Won't Center in CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, center

EDIT: [Here's a jsfiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/4YXZz/)

**EDIT 2: I think it's being overridden by the Twitter Bootstrap stylesheet that I'm using, too. I'll figure out what's wrong in there. Thanks for the help, guys.**

Here's what my form looks like right now:

[image]

Ideally I'd like the search bar and submit button to be centered (equal margins to the left of the search bar and to the right of the button).

My CSS doesn't seem to be working:

```
body {
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:5%;
    background:url(/img/bg.png);
    background-position:center;
    background-position:top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:0b334c;
}

.searchContainer {
    width:440px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    zoom:1;
}

.searchBox {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;
    background-color:#6eb0d9;
    background-color:#6eb0d9;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-image:-khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#9cd1e9), to(#6eb0d9));
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #9cd1e9, #6eb0d9);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #9cd1e9, #6eb0d9);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #9cd1e9), color-stop(100%, #6eb0d9));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #9cd1e9, #6eb0d9);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #9cd1e9, #6eb0d9);
    background-image:linear-gradient(top, #9cd1e9, #6eb0d9);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9cd1e9', endColorstr='#6eb0d9', GradientType=0);
}

.searchBox form {
    display:inline-block;
}

.searchBox h2 {
    letter-spacing:-0.05em;
    padding-bottom:8px;
}

.searchBar {
    border: double;
    height:31px;
    width:357px;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-image:-khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eee), to(#fff));
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #fff);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #fff);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #eee), color-stop(100%, #fff));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #fff);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #fff);
    background-image:linear-gradient(top, #eee, #fff);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eee', endColorstr='#fff', GradientType=0);
}

input.searchButton {
    position:fixed;
    height: 31px;
    width: 33px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background:url(../img/searchButton-Off.png) no-repeat;
} 

input.searchButton:hover { 
    position:fixed;
    height: 31px;
    width: 33px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background:url(../img/searchButton-On.png) no-repeat;
}
```

---

```
  <div class="searchBox">
    <h2 style="color:#000000;">Search</h2>
    <form id="form_297586" class="appnitro"  method="get" action="results.php">
      <input id="keywords" name="keywords" class="searchBar" title="What do you like...?" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>
      &nbsp;<input type="submit" class="searchButton" value="" />
      <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="297586" />
      <input type="hidden" name="src" value="n" />
      <input type="hidden" name="fancy" value="y" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A jsfiddle demo would be helpful.

Comment: what browser are you using ? i test in chrome it's centred

Comment: Safari and Opera. For whatever reason my Chrome keeps crashing (unrelated to site), so I had to use some other browsers.

Comment: It centres for me, but only if I remove the `position: fixed` from the CSS. [But then the button drops down for some reason...](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4YXZz/1/) =/ (Chrome 18/Win XP).

Comment: Yeah, that's why I added in the position:fixed. I was having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work was by removing the `position: fixed` from the search-button, and search-bar (`input`s), and then adding `position: relative; top: -9px;` to the `.searchButton` element.

Which feels dirty, to be honest; and I don't know *why* that should be required.

Anyway, a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4YXZz/3/).

Comment: That seems to work. Strange, though, that that's required. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome! I just wish that I knew *why* it worked, and why it's required. I don't even know why it's `9px` and not `14px` (or, frankly, any *other* number...). Sigh... =/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this class to your css:

```
.appnitro { margin: 0 auto; }
```

You might need to set a width on the form.

And hit Ctrl+F5 when refreshing =)

Comment: No luck. Not sure why that didn't work. It's probably being overridden by some other CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you can warp the form inside a div, give a size and set margin left and right to auto

http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/WbTLr/

Comment: I thought for sure this would work, but it's still not centering.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on jsfiddle, and I saw that it's actually your search bar that is perfectly centered. The submit button just stays to the right of it. 
Remove `position:fixed` from `input.searchButton` class and add:

```
position: relative;
bottom: 8px;
```

This is because if you remove the `position:fixed` the whole thing centers, but the submit button moves down a bit. So that's a tiny hack to nudge it up.

[jsFiddle working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dvidby0/bRuxA/)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do when I need to center something:

#### Styles:

```
div.centera {
    float: right;
    left: -50%;
    position: relative;
}
div.centerb {
    float: right; 
    left: 50%;  
    position: relative;
}
```

#### And centering contents:

```
<div class="centera">
    <div class="centerb">
        <div>Should be in center</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT:

Tried it and it worked well in chromium after adding `float: left;` for  `<input id="keywords"...`

Anyway I think that `float: left` should added for button too...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do when I need to center something:

```css
.centera {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centera">
  <p>center Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap the form in center tags.

Comment: He could; but he really, *really*, ***really*** shouldn't. [Since it's been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/center).

Comment: So why is everyone against center tags? No one gave a reasonable explanation.

Comment: @AndrewG.H. Well, it's not a good practice to use deprecated tags, because they might disappear some day. So why take the chance when you're creating something from start?